# Kotlin bytecode in Android Apps

Tags: android, kotlin, decompiler

I'm a kotlin and Java developer, and recently I started analyzing the bytecode generated by kotlin. And I found out a lot of wrapper code and other stuff that the compiler generates in order to translate what I have coded in Kotlin to Java.

**So, my question is:**

*Imagine that I have an app that its code is 100% written in kotlin.* Dependencies and the main app. All Kotlin.

1. Does this mean that a different compiler will be used in order to avoid Java compatible bytecode?
2. Or is there any optimization done by the compiler in this kind of scenarios?

Many Thanks.

---

I know about `Kotlin Native` but I think it will only be applied to Android in the future.

Comment: What do you mean by *in order to avoid bytecode?*

Comment: kotlin has its own compiler, yes

Comment: @TimCastelijns but it still becomes Java bytecode, although it's an absolute mess.

Comment: What leads you to say "an absolute mess?" It's not.

Comment: @yole Well I guess I don't know about the bytecode, but when it's decompiled, using Android Studio's decompiler, JADx or APKTool (Java, Java, Smali), it's much harder to follow the code vs a Java app. Kotlin classes also still use `kotlin.String`, `kotlin.Int` and `kotlin.Unit` types when compiled, instead of `java.lang.String`, `int` and `void`.

Comment: @leonardkraemer I mean avoid Java compatible bytecode.

Comment: _"I mean avoid Java compatible bytecode"_ The Android runtime (whether ART or Dalvik) expects DEX bytecode. If you decided to compile your Kotlin code into some other kind of bytecode you'd no longer be able to run your apps on any Android devices (unless you were to bundle an entire VM that handles that custom bytecode).

Comment: @TheWanderer They don't. There is no `kotlin.String.class`, the bytecode uses  regular Java strings. You see `kotlin.String` if you look at Kotlin libraries which don't have source code in IntelliJ IDEA; this shows you decoded Kotlin metadata, not Java bytecode.

Comment: @yole you're right about that, sorry, but I still maintain that decompiling Kotlin classes results in a mess. For one, extension functions just get added to every class they're used in, instead of something less boilerplatey, like a static method in a generic class. Another is the `by lazy` init.

Comment: Extension functions do not get added to every class they're used in; they are compiled to static methods. You might be confusing them with inline functions.

Comment: @yole I just decompiled one of my apps and saw an extension function in a class.

Comment: @TheWanderer as someone who has worked on Kotlin bytecode generation, I'm quite certain it does not copy extension functions. You're welcome to post a separate question with a code snippet and a description of how you're decompiling it, and I'll explain what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you're going to avoid Java bytecode with Kotlin is to use Kotlin Native, and you won't be able to use the Android SDK in that case.

Kotlin JVM, as the name implies, compiles to JVM bytecode; it's one of the main draws of using it. If it compiled to something different, it would be Kotlin Native.

To answer your bullets:

1. No, the same compiler is used whether or not you have Java source files.
2. Probably not. Kotlin JVM is made to be almost completely interoperable with Java, and that's the same whether or not your project includes Java code.

Think about if you were creating an Android library in Kotlin. Would you really want it to automatically compile to something other than Java bytecode in that case? It wouldn't be able to be used in Java projects, defeating one of the main reasons Kotlin is so good as a Java alternative.

Also remember, you're using the Android SDK. Even if you have no dependencies in your build.gradle, you still reference the core SDK itself, which is Java. The SDK isn't included in your APK, but it's still used during compilation.

If you want something that avoids Java bytecode, use something like Flutter. It has its own SDK, and can bridge back to Java components. Of course, you can't completely avoid the JVM, because you still need some way for Android to install and open the app.